# Image of semialgebraic set is a semialgebraic set

Tags: algebraic-geometry, semialgebraic-geometry

> Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$, where $m\le n$, be a linear map that maps all points with rational coordinates to the points with rational coordinates. Prove that the $f(A)$ is semialgebraic if $A$ is semialgebraic set.

From Tarski–Seidenberg theorem we know that projection is a semialgebraic set, but how to deal with a linear map, which can not be a projection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the graph $\Gamma_f\subset \Bbb R^n\times \Bbb R^m$. This can be written as the zero set of a collection of linear equations, so it's semialgebraic. Next, intersect $\Gamma_f$ with the set $A\times \Bbb R^m$, which is semialgebraic as the product of semialgebraic sets is semialgebraic. But this intersection is exactly $(a,f(a))$ for $a\in A$, so by projection to $\Bbb R^m$ we see that we get $f(A)$ as a semialgebraic set.

This same procedure works in general to show that the image of a semialgebraic set under a semialgebraic map (defined as a map with semialgebraic graph) is again semialgebraic.

Comment: Why graph can be written as the zero set?

Comment: Write $x_i$ for coordinates on $\Bbb R^n$ and $y_j$ for coordinates on $\Bbb R^m$. Then the linear map is given by $y_j=\sum a_{ij}x_i$, and these are the equations which determine the graph in $\Bbb R^n\times \Bbb R^m$.

Comment: But what if the coordinate is irrational? Or $x_i, y_j$ are parameters?

Comment: $x_i$ and $y_j$ are the standard coordinates on $\Bbb R^n$ and $\Bbb R^m$, respectively. Nothing about the rationality/irrationality of any of them affects the argument. Maybe an example will help: think about the linear map $\Bbb R\to  \Bbb R$ given by multiplication by a constant $a$. Then the graph of this morphism is the line with equation $y-ax$ inside $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: It seems clearly logical, I'm just confused about how this graph should look like (I've never seen such way of proof) and is it true that its intersection should not contain all points from A?

Comment: The graph of $f$ is just a copy of $\Bbb R^n$ embedded in a slightly interesting way inside $\Bbb R^n\times \Bbb R^m$: it's $(x,f(x))$. I don't understand the second clause of your sentence - the intersection $\Gamma_f\cap (A\times \Bbb R^m)$ contains all points of the form $(a,f(a))$, so once you project it to $\Bbb R^m$, you get that its image is exactly $f(A)$. Can you clarify your issue?

Comment: Yes, I think I understood what isn't clear for me. The semialgebraic set is a finite set of equations/inequalities, why graph, written as a zero set, is semialgebraic in this case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100769/discussion-between-kreiser-and-ronald-s-merritt).